# Бесконечное вращения Фона

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как сделать, так чтобы Div prof-cont стоял на месте, а фон вращался постоянно, но при этом не выходя за границы prof-cont overflow hidden вроде.

```js
var angle = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  angle += 3;
  $(".prof").rotate(angle);
}, 40);
```

```css
.prof {
  padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<div class="profile">
  <div class="prof">
    <div class="pro-cont">Ты умер '.$prof[death].' раз,убил '.$prof[kil].' игроков,добил до смерти '.$prof[animal].' животных.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может быть вам надо `.profile {
      overflow: hidden;
    }`, раз вы вращаете `prof` ?

Comment: Текст должен стоять на месте).Он вращяется...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.profile {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.profile:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotate-0-360 8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-0-360 {
  from { transform: rotate(0); }
  to { transform: rotate(1turn); }
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
  <div class="pro-cont">Ты умер '.$prof[death].' раз,убил '.$prof[kil].' игроков,добил до смерти '.$prof[animal].' животных.</div>
</div>
```